# What should I include using the mergExt mergSettings in my Livecode app

Tags: livecode

I downloaded the mergSettings and the InAppSettingsKit. I noticed in the standalone application settings for the demo app in mergSettings that there are many .nib files listed but I can not find the equivalent in either the mergSettings download or the InAppSettingsKit.

Is there a tutorial on how to include the mergSettings in a Livecode App? If not, what files should be included and from where?

Comment: The reason I asked this question was that the build using the demo that comes with mergSettings crashes on a device and upon further investigation i noticed that the demo app contained dead links in the standalone application settings - copy files pane.

Comment: just uploaded 1.0.4 with the nib files

Comment: and... I just uploaded 1.0.5 with a sample settings bundle ;-)

Answer (score 0):

See this youtube video for the how to set the inclusions in the copy files pane http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zFTsVu7_QOI

However it appears the required nib files are missing in 1.0.3 so I'll get them up there ASAP